# How to apply a loop in xml report for odoo 8?

Tags: xml, odoo

The following is the rml report code I used in openerp 7:

```
<para style="terp_default_2">[[ repeatIn([line for line in picking.move_lines if ((line.state == 'confirmed' or line.state=='done' or line.state=='assigned') and not line.scrapped)],'move_lines') ]]</para>
```

I need to convert this to odoo 8. How can I apply the same condition in XML report for odoo 8?
The following is an example of looping in odoo 8 xml report:

```
<tr t-foreach="o.order_line" t-as="l">
```

I need to apply the same condition used in rml for a similar loop.

Thanks And Regards,

Yaseen Shareef

Comment: Do you mean Qweb report? OR is it regular xml view? What is your actual requirement?

Comment: If you have gone through reports in odoo 8, you might have noticed the xml report in views folder. I am talking about reports, the pdfs, for ex: sale order report.

Comment: use t-if for if conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U want to use for loop in qweb report ?

Example:

```
<tr t-foreach="get_payslip_lines(o.line_ids)" t-as="p">
    <td><span t-field="p.code"/></td>
    <td><span t-field="p.name"/></td>
    <td>
        <t t-if="p.amount &lt; 0"> <span t-esc="formatLang(-p.amount, currency_obj=o.company_id.currency_id)"/></t>
        <t t-if="p.amount &gt;=  0"><span t-esc="formatLang(p.amount, currency_obj=o.company_id.currency_id)"/></t>
    </td>
    <td>
        <t t-if="p.total &lt; 0"> <span t-esc="formatLang(-p.total, currency_obj=o.company_id.currency_id)"/></t>
        <t t-if="p.total &gt;=  0"><span t-esc="formatLang(p.total, currency_obj=o.company_id.currency_id)"/></t>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is sample using for loop and if to convert negative value in payslip printed as normal(without - symbol)